# play audio file from where i pause, not from the beginning in Audioplayers flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new in flutter ... I want to play audio file from where i pause, not from the beginning in **`audioplayers`** flutter package ...

in this example there is just:
1- play from the beginning 
2- pause
3- stop

pause and stop they have same function because by pause i can not play from where i pause ...

so what i want is to play from where i pause, in same button!

the **`audioplayers`** package which I use

> https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

my code ...

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef void OnError(Exception exception);

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,home:  LocalAudio()));
}

class LocalAudio extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocalAudio createState() =>  _LocalAudio();
}

class _LocalAudio extends State<LocalAudio> {
  Duration _duration = new Duration();
  Duration _position = new Duration();
  AudioPlayer advancedPlayer;
  AudioCache audioCache;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlayer();
  }

  void initPlayer() {
    advancedPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    audioCache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer);

    advancedPlayer.durationHandler = (d) => setState(() {
          _duration = d;
        });

    advancedPlayer.positionHandler = (p) => setState(() {
          _position = p;
        });
  }

  String localFilePath;

  Widget _tab(List<Widget> children) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: children
                .map((w) => Container(child: w, padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0)))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _btn(String txt, VoidCallback onPressed) {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: 48.0,
      child: Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 45,
        child: RaisedButton(
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
            child: Text(txt),
            color: Colors.pink[900],
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: onPressed),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget slider() {
    return Slider(
        activeColor: Colors.black,
        inactiveColor: Colors.pink,
        value: _position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        min: 0.0,
        max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        onChanged: (double value) {
          setState(() {
            seekToSecond(value.toInt());
            value = value;
          });
        });
  }

  Widget LocalAudio() {
    return _tab([
      _btn('Play', () => audioCache.play('disco.mp3')),
      _btn('Pause', () => advancedPlayer.pause()),
      _btn('Stop', () => advancedPlayer.stop()),
      slider()
    ]);
  }

  void seekToSecond(int second) {
    Duration newDuration = Duration(seconds: second);

    advancedPlayer.seek(newDuration);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 1,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 1.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          title: Center(child: Text('LOCAL AUDIO')),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [LocalAudio()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a function in `class AudioPlayer` for `resume`

it is look like this in `class AudioPlayer`

```
Future<int> resume() async {
    final int result = await _invokeMethod('resume');

    if (result == 1) {
      state = AudioPlayerState.PLAYING;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

to use it add 
 `_btn('resume', () => advancedPlayer.resume()),`

below line of 
 `_btn('Pause', () => advancedPlayer.pause()),`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the resume method to play the audio from where you paused it.

```
await audioPlayer.resume();
```

It only works if the audioPlayer state is Paused.

From the package documentation:

> Also, you can resume (like play, but without new parameters):
>
> `int result = await audioPlayer.resume();`

Comment: It was a general example. You have to use your audioPlayer object name  which is advancedPlayer I suppose. So when you’re player is paused you can resume it by this: await advancedPlayer.resume();

Answer (score 0):

`resume()` method has been removed, we just need to play again if paused without any condition (in new update) like below.
`advancedPlayer.play();`

Hope it helps someone in future.

Comment: As stated: `resume()` „only works if the audioPlayer state is Paused.“ you need to check for that.

Comment: resume() method is not defined in audiopPlayer package probably in newer update.